# Upload multiple pictures renaming files in Codeigniter 3

Tags: file, codeigniter, upload

I'm not able to figure out what's wrong in my code.

In my project the user is allowed to upload multiple pictures for each aircraft registration number; I want to rename each uploaded files with the following rules: registration id, minus sign, progressive number; so if the user upload a new image file for the registration id xxx, the uploaded filename becomes xxx-1.jpg

The code to upload the multiple files is the following; it works fine so far...

```
// Count uploaded files
$countfiles = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
// Define new image name
$image = $id . '-1.jpg';

for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++)
{
    if(!empty($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]))
    {
        // Define new $_FILES array - $_FILES['file']
        $_FILES['file']['name'] = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['type'] = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['error'] = $_FILES['files']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['size'] = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];

        // Check if the image file exist and modify name in case
        $filename = $this->_file_newname($uploaddir,$image);
        
        // Set preference
        $config['upload_path'] = $upload_path; 
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
        $config['max_size'] = '5000';
        $config['file_name'] = $filename;

        //Load upload library
        $this->load->library('upload',$config); 
        $arr = array('msg' => 'something went wrong', 'success' => false);
        // File upload
        if($this->upload->do_upload('file'))
        {
            $data = $this->upload->data(); 
        }
    }
}
```

The _file_newname() function does the file renaming jog, here you are the code:

```
private function _file_newname($path, $filename)
{
    if ($pos = strrpos($filename, '.')) {
        $name = substr($filename, 0, $pos);
        $ext = substr($filename, $pos);
    } else {
        $name = $filename;
    }
    $newpath = $path.$filename;
    $newname = $filename;
    if(file_exists($newpath)){
        $counter = 1;
        if($pos = strrpos($name, '-')) {
            $oldcounter = substr($name, $pos + 1);
            if(is_numeric($oldcounter)){
                $counter = $oldcounter++;
                $name = substr($name, 0, $pos);
            }
        }
        $newname = $name . '-' . $counter . $ext;
        $newpath = $path . $newname;

        while (file_exists($newpath)) {
            $newname = $name .'-'. $counter . $ext;
            $newpath = $path.$newname;
            $counter++;
        }
    }
    return $newname;
}
```

Now...the issue....the renaming function works fine if the user upload one file each time...so the first upload set the file name xxx-1.jpg, the second upload set the filename to xxx-2.jpg and so on....but....if the user upload more then one file at time...the second file become xxx-1x.jpg.
If already exists one file on server ( for example xxx-1.jpg ) and the user upload two more files..they are renamed as xxx-2.jpg ( correct) and xxx-21.jpg (wrong...should be xxx-3.jpg).

Any hint or suggestion to fix the issue?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new file name is out of the loop for the uploaded photos.
So it becomes static.

Put that line inside the loop:

// Define new image name
$image = $id . '-' . $i . '.jpg';

This way you are gonna keep the $id and rename the files according to the iteration of the loop - $i.